# List of all restaurants in a city (EU)?

Tags: data-request, city, europe

Is there an open database where I can get the list of all restaurants (or bakeries, etc) for a given city ?

Since I'd need theses places so as to be able to put them on a map, like Google maps, i would need the following:

- geo cordinates
- name

Does such a database exists? If not, is it possible to get the request results from Google maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here is my obligatory pointer to **overpass turbo**, a "graphic" way to explore the data quality for certain POIs (points of interest) in the OpenStreetMap database.

This [examplary query for `amenity=restaurant` in Rome](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/5JS) (patience: the query takes several seconds to execute) yields (probably incomplete) 543 locations with varying metadata.

[image: 543 restaurants in/around rome as points on a map]

**How-to:** For a given POI, find out its most canonical way of tagging through the page [Map Features](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features) on the OSM Wiki. Then use the "Wizard" button on overpass turbo to generate the query. Browse the map to a suitable test location and hit execute. The map then can be navigated and the POIs inspected for data quality.

Answer (score 5):

I would take a look at these sources:

- OpenStreetMap (OSM)

  - [All about POIs (points of interest) in OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Points_of_interest)
  - [Question on help.OSM about extracting POIs from a region](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/12608/extract-pois-for-a-region)
- Foursquare

  - [POI API (aka Venues)](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) (note: not open data)
- Yelp

  - [Search](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api) / [Business](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business) APIs (note: not open data)

Comment: Note: Foursquare and Yelp are not Open Data

Comment: Thanks @NicolasRaoul. Despite the name of the site, answers with "closed" data are also appreciated. http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/203/1511

Comment: @philshem: I think that adding a small note should be expected when adding non-open data. Ideally all items should mention the license.

Answer (score 4):

For Great Britain, the [Food Standards Authority](http://www.food.gov.uk/) make available an [API](http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/en-GB) which has the food hygiene ratings for every place that serves food in [the local authorities that operate the scheme](http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/en-GB).

Whilst this data does include places not normally open to the public (there are some office canteens, schools, etc.) their data is reasonably well classified and free to use - as always, the should read and understand the licence prior to using the data.