# Dataset of Japanese company industries and HQ locations?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, companies, japan

Does there exist a dataset containing information (historical or current) on the following characteristics of Japanese companies?

1. Industries (e.g. *"electronics"*).
2. Headquarter addresses (e.g. *"3-23-14 Higashi-Ikebukuro, Toshima-Ku, Tokyo, 170-0013"*). Latitudes/longitudes would be even better.

---

The [dataset](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/databreakdown.html) maintained by Aswath Damadaran at Stern seems extensive, but it only includes per-company industries, not HQ addresses.

The Tokyo Stock Exchange [listed company search](http://www2.tse.or.jp/tseHpFront/JJK020030Action.do) seemed promising, but as far as I can tell, although they provide per-company industries, their provided HQ addresses only specify the city, not the full address.

Comment: Have you checked out the OSM resources? for example http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3953/1511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [opencorporates](https://opencorporates.com/). They provide a nice api to download data.
Recently they have added database of [4.4 million japan companies](https://blog.opencorporates.com/2016/11/02/4-4-million-japan-companies-added-to-opencorporates/).

Search for **SoftBank**  gives

```
Company Number   3010401116655
Status   Active
Company Type   Stock Company (株式会社)
Jurisdiction Japan
Registered Address  東新橋１丁目９番１号
                    港区
                    1050021
                    東京都
                    Japan

Registry Page        http://www.houjin-bangou.nta.go.jp/he...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a search on RapidAPI for "Japan Company Data" you can get a number of resources, for example; https://rapidapi.com/appaio/api/japan-company-data/

This source returns data as follows (Example)

```
corporate_number:"1011002012816"
postal_code:"1500013"
location:"東京都渋谷区恵比寿２丁目５番８号サン・クオーレ７０２"
name:"有限会社間宮商店"
status:"-"
number_of_activity:"0"
update_date:"2015-10-28T00:00:00+09:00"
```